# Recursive SQL and information on different level

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by

Is it possible to display, in the same query, information concerning different level of recursivity ?

```
select LEVEL, ae2.CAB, ae2.NIVEAU, ae2.ENTITE, ae2.ENTITE_PARENT, ae2.libelle
from my_table ae2
where ae2.NIVEAU = 2
start with ae2.cab = 'XXX'
connect by prior ae2.entite_parent = ae2.entite
```

With this query I have (let's say) 4 levels of information about the entity above root 'XXX'

Is it possible to display root information at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to use the [CONNECT_BY_ROOT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/operators004.htm#SQLRF0031) operator. For instance, if you wanted the `cab` of the parent your query would be:

```
select connect_by_root cab
      , level, cab, niveau, entite, entite_parent, libelle
   from my_table
  where niveau = 2
  start with cab = 'XXX'
connect by prior entite_parent = entite
```

You have to use a new operator for each column you want to select. You *won't* get information from a "different" level of recursivity using this operator, only from the root. If you want more you'll have to use [recursive subquery factoring.](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause.php)